# Remove trailing zeros from phone number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an old Phone table which has a PhonoNo column with length 15. Now I am working on a task for phone number cleanup with trailing 0s after 10 digits.

```
+----------------+---------------+
|    PhoneNo     | Desire output |
+----------------+---------------+
|198765432100000 |    1987654321 |
|   198765432100 |    1987654321 |
|     1987653210 |    1987653210 |
|    19876543210 |    1987654321 |
|198765432100100 | 1987654321001 |
|       19876543 |      19876543 |
|      009876543 |     009876543 |
+----------------+---------------+
```

I am using the below code but it does not work for me.

```
SELECT PhoneNo, REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(PhoneNo,'0',' ')),' ','0') as NewPhoneNo 
FROM tblPhone WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I am looking for a solution in SQL Server to remove trailing 0s without creating any function.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Remove trailing 0's from a phone number? Then you can't call me anymore.

Comment: `after 10 digits.` ? Then why all the trailing zeros for `98765432100000`  are removed

Comment: stop using WITH(NOLOCK) !

Comment: But `198765432100100` will not fit in 10 characters after trimming. Your problem is more complex than you think.

Comment: @SMor, It looks you have some problems in understanding the question. Anyway it got resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression to return values with less than or equal to 10 characters as they are, then then `REPLACE` and `RTRIM` to remove the trailing 0's:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(PhoneNo) <= 10 THEN PhoneNo
            ELSE REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(PhoneNo,'0',' ')),' ','0')
       END
FROM (VALUES ('198765432100000'),
             ('198765432100'),
             ('1987653210'),
             ('19876543210'),
             ('198765432100100'),
             ('19876543'),
             ('009876543'))V(PhoneNo);
```

Comment: This not working for `00000000000`. Ideally, it is should trim to 10 characters.

Comment: Honestly, not going to even address that example, @Arshad . That's silly to have a phone number made up of all zeroes and you're adding multiple more arbitrary requirements.

Comment: I think this can be done by substring till 10 characters + your existing replace functionality on the rest of the characters.

Comment: It worked for me `SELECT SUBSTRING(PhoneNo, 1, 10) + 
    REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PhoneNo, 11, LEN(PhoneNo)-10),'0',' ')),' ','0')
FROM (VALUES ('000100000000'), ('00000000000'))V(PhoneNo)` . Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A possible option is the `TRIM()` function (SQL Server 2017+ is required). By default the `TRIM()` function removes the space character or other specified characters from the start and end of a string, so you need to put an additional character (`#` in the example) at the correct positions (1st and 10th) and remove it after that:

```
SELECT 
   REPLACE(
      TRIM('0' FROM '#' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNo, 1, 10) + '#' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNo, 11, 5)),
      '#',
      ''
   ) AS PhoneNo   
FROM (VALUES
   ('19876543210000'),
   ('198765432100'),
   ('1987653210'),
   ('19876543210'),
   ('198765432100100'),
   ('19876543'),
   ('009876543')
) t (PhoneNo)
```

Result:

```
PhoneNo
-------------
1987654321
1987654321
1987653210
1987654321
1987654321001
19876543
009876543
```

Comment: how it is going to work for `987653210`

Comment: @Arshad, what is the expected result `987653210` (because the phone number is 10 digits) or `98765321`?

Comment: desired result is `987653210 ` (because the phone number is 10 digits)

Comment: @Arshad, then what is the expected result for `98765432100000` - `9876543210` or `987654321`?

Comment: I have update example data in  the question

Comment: @Arshad, the answer is updated.

Comment: I am getting an error when I execute your query : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: @Arshad, SQL Server 2017 is required to use the `TRIM()` function. What is the error message?

Comment: CONCAT function is a bit less dependent on SQL dialect.

Comment: Even `SUBSTRING` is dependant though, @Taemyr . In some dialects it's `SUBSTR`. It is honestly, more a pipe dream if you want to write anything more than rudimentary SQL that will be runnable in many dialects.

Comment: Error message is : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' when I run ms SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of string functions `LEFT` `PATINDEX` `REVERSE` as follows:

```
SELECT PhoneNo, 
       Left(PhoneNo, 
            IIF(Len(PhoneNo)-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',Reverse(PhoneNo))+1<=10 Or PhoneNo Like '%[^1-9]%', 
                10,
                Len(PhoneNo)-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', Reverse(PhoneNo))+1)) As NewPhoneNo 
FROM tblPhone
```

Output:

```
PhoneNo              NewPhoneNo
-------------------- --------------------
19876543210000       1987654321
198765432100         1987654321
1987653210           1987653210
19876543210          1987654321
198765432100100      1987654321001
19876543             19876543
009876543            009876543
```

Answer (score 0):

or shorter:

```
SELECT IIF(LEN(PhoneNo) <= 10, PhoneNo, REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(PhoneNo, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'))
```

[This is based on Larnu's answer]

Comment: This is not working for `00000000000`